# What's the difference between composer require vs manually modifying composer.json

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there any difference between typing in the console:

```
composer require facebook/php-sdk-v4
```

vs. editing composer.json and adding the following line:

```
"facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use it automatically, composer automatically takes the lastest package according to your current installation.

When you do it mannually, you need to specify the version by hand.

Comment: You can also specify a the version constraint as a command line argument, eg: `composer require monolog/monolog "1.5.*"`

Comment: Yes you can, but if you don't Composer will guess it automatically, thing that doing manually won't be achieved.